# Problem thinning out polygon layers to find polygon centerlines

Tags: arcmap

I have a polygon layer representing road surfacing layers. My task was to "thin out" the polygons in order to come up with a network of 'road centerlines' (dark green).

I generated this new polyline layer as follows in ArcMap:

- Rasterized the road surfacing layer to a generously high resolution
- Binarized the road surfacing layer where values of 1 indicate presence of road and values of 0 indicate no presence of road.
- Thinned out the raster layer
- Vectorized the thinned raster layer using "Raster to Polyline" tool

The result is conceptually OK since it does somehow find the centerlines of the polygons. However I am ending up with some really ugly artifacts as follows which originate from the thinned raster:

[image]

Zooming in a bit closer:

[image]

Now I am doubting whether this approach is appropriate, since it generates so many defects that would take an unreasonable amount of time to fix manually.

How can I either :

- automate the fixing of these defects
- prevent that these defects occur in the first place? I.e using another method for example...

Answer (score 1):

First, you could use "collapse dual lines to centerline" if you had the advanced licence.

Concerning your method, you should use a larger maximum distance with your thin command. This would explain your artefacts.